I cannot install the dependencies libpq-devel on my AlmaLinux 8.9 server for Superset
sudo yum install libpq-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 1:21:49 ago on Wed 08 May 2024 12:44:27 PM -05.
Error:
Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job

nothing provides perl(IPC::Run) needed by postgresql16-devel-16.2-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 from pgdg16
nothing provides perl(IPC::Run) needed by postgresql15-devel-15.6-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 from pgdg15
nothing provides perl(IPC::Run) needed by postgresql14-devel-14.11-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 from pgdg14
nothing provides perl(IPC::Run) needed by postgresql13-devel-13.14-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 from pgdg13
nothing provides perl(IPC::Run) needed by postgresql12-devel-12.18-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 from pgdg12
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

I got this error every time i´m trying to install libpq-devel thats needed for psycopg2.
Try alredy with other dependencies like libpq-dev also i alredy try installing perl-CPAN and IPC::Run

Seems this package's repo (comes with powertools repo) is not enabled by default on AlmaLinux 8.
To enable the repo;
dnf install epel-release
dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools

Now it should display under the repo list;
dnf repolist

Now it should be ready to install
dnf install perl-IPC-Run

